# Android Andengine Background music duplicate itself

Tags: java, android, andengine, background-music

I'm developing a game via Andengine for Android. I have ResourseManager and SceneManager calsses. I loaded background music with ResourceManger. and use it in MenuScene. When I change the scene and come back the menu scene again, background music is duplicating itself. why can it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must unload your sound resources when changing scene from the ResourceManager class. Otherwise the sound object will still be there.